# Ruby gsub : is there a better way

Tags: ruby

I need to remove all leading and trailing non-numeric characters. This is what I came up with. Is there a better implementation.

```
puts s.gsub(/^\D+/,'').gsub(/\D+$/,'')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of eliminating what you don't want, it's often clearer to select what you do want (using parentheses). Also, this only requires one regex evaluation:

```
s.match(/^\D*(.*?)\D*$/)[1]
```

Or, this convenient shorthand:

```
s[/^\D*(.*?)\D*$/, 1]
```

Comment: Or possibly a simpler regular expression depending on what kind of strings you have.
`"abc123def"[/\d+/] # => "123"`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a single `#gsub(/(^\D+)|(\D+$)/, '')`

Also, when in doubt [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) it.