# Using select rather than gsub to avoid multiple regex evaluations in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Here is one output that requires multiple regex evaluations but gets what I want to do done (remove everything except the text).

```
words = IO.read("file.txt").
gsub(/\s/, ""). # delete white spaces
gsub(".",""). # delete periods
gsub(",",""). # delete commas
gsub("?","") # delete Q marks
puts words
# output
#      WheninthecourseofhumaneventsitbecomesnecessaryIwanttobelieveyoureallyIdobutwhoamItoblameWhenthefactsarecountedthenumberswillbereportedLotsoflaughsCharlieIthinkIheardthatonetentimesbefore
```

Looking at this post - [Ruby gsub : is there a better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943975/ruby-gsub-is-there-a-better-way) - I figured I would try to do a match to accomplish the same result without multiple regex evaluations. But I don't get the same output.

```
words = IO.read("file.txt").
match(/(\w*)+/)
puts words
# output - this only gets the first word
# When
```

And this only gets the first sentence:

```
words = IO.read("file.txt").
match(/(...*)+/)
puts words

# output - this only gets the first sentence
# When in the course of human events it becomes necessary.
```

Any suggestions on getting the same output (including stripping out white spaces and non-word characters) on a match rather than gsub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want in one gsub operation:

```
s = 'When in the course of human events it becomes necessary.'
s.gsub /[\s.,?]/, ''
# => "Wheninthecourseofhumaneventsitbecomesnecessary"
```

Comment: Thanks Hck. I think I got it. This evaluates any whitespace character (\s), period mark (.) comma (,) or question mark (?) and replaces it with nothing (because nothing is between the quotes). Helpful. Just need to keep working on getting the hang of regex.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple regex evaluations for this.

```
str = "# output - this only gets the first sentence
# When in the course of human events it becomes necessary."
p str.gsub(/\W/, "")
#=>"outputthisonlygetsthefirstsentenceWheninthecourseofhumaneventsitbecomesnecessary"
```

Comment: Got it. Replace any non-word character (\W) with nothing (""). OK, duly informed. I must have over analyzed this! Thanks.